# how to sp_refreshsqlmodule with procedure that are prefixed with a schema

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

When I try EXEC sp_refreshsqlmodule [myschema.myprocedure] it throws Could not find object 'myschema.myprocedure' or you do not have permission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the object is schema-bound, then the metadata cannot become outdated because the object is bound to the underlying objects that it references.

EDIT:
Based on your edit, the procedure name should be enclosed in single quotes:

```
EXEC sp_refreshsqlmodule 'myschema.myprocedure'
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue I had to do it like this :

EXEC sp_refreshsqlmodule '[myschema].[myprocedure]'